# Regex to allow only a single dot in a textbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I have one text input.

I wrote a regex for masking all special characters except `.` and `-`. Now if by mistake the user enters two `.` (dots) in input, then with the current regex

```
var valueTest='225..36'

valueTest.match(/[^-.\d]/)
```

I expected that the number will not pass this condition

How to handle this case. I just want *one* `.` (dot) in input field since it is a number.

Comment: did you want to allow the numbers which has one dot?

Comment: can you show us more example? such as allow hyphens formate

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I think you mean this,

```
^-?\d+(?:\.\d+)?$
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/lP2hO0/5)

It allows positive and negative numbers with or without decimal points.

**EXplanation:**

- `^` Asserts that we are at the start.
- `-?` Optional `-` symbol.
- `\d+` Matches one or more numbers.
- `(?:` start of non-capturing group.
- `\.` Matches a literal dot.
- `\d+` Matches one or more numbers.
- `?` Makes the whole non-capturing group as optional.
- `$` Asserts that we are at the end.

Answer (score 3):

if you just want to handle number ,you can try this:

```
valueTest.match(/^-?\d+(\.\d+)?$/)
```

Comment: for negative numbers `-?\d+(\.\d+)?` ... best: `[+-]?\d+(\.\d+)?`

Comment: @AvinashRaj :) yes,your answer is similar to me as I answer earlier, ha~ ha~

Answer (score 2):

You can probably avoid regex altogether with this case.

**For instance**

```
String[] input = { "225.36", "225..36","-225.36", "-225..36" };
for (String s : input) {
    try {
        Double d = Double.parseDouble(s);
        System.out.printf("\"%s\" is a number.%n", s);
    }
    catch (NumberFormatException nfe) {
        System.out.printf("\"%s\" is not a valid number.%n", s);
    }
}
```

**Output**

```
"225.36" is a number.
"225..36" is not a valid number.
"-225.36" is a number.
"-225..36" is not a valid number.
```

Comment: @techfoobar hyphens are allowed in this solution as long as they precede the number --> negative doubles.

Comment: Other than not being javascript, this answer is the best approach. It's light, and simple, and taking advantage of javascript's loose types it can be done in one line. `valid = parseFloat(currentValue) == currentValue ? true : false;`

Answer (score 2):

Use below reg ex it will meet your requirements.

/^\d+(.\d+)?$/

Comment: .(dot) should escape first in regex

Comment: ohh yep it should be /^-?\d+(\.\d+)?$/