# What's wrong with this code to allow only number and period?

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, html, dojo

I have the below HTML code that will accept only numbers and NOT alphabets. I want it to accept period too. What's wrong with this? I don't want to use a different jQuery or javascript function to call on key press. I want to go with the same way I used but should allow period too. How? Thanks.

```
<input onkeypress="return /\d/.test(String.fromCharCode(((event||window.event).which||    (event||window.event).which)));" 
ondrop="return false" onpaste="return false" maxlength="8" type="text" />
```

Comment: you mean ' onkeypress="return ^[\d.]+$/\d/.test(String.fromCharCode(((event||window.event).which||    (event||window.event).which)));" '  ??

Comment: no, `/^[.\d]+$/.test`

Comment: <input onkeypress="return /[\d\.\,]/.test(String.fromCharCode(((event||window.event).which||    (event||window.event).which)));" 
ondrop="return false" onpaste="return false" maxlength="8" type="text" />

Answer (score 1):

Just put `\d` and `.` inside a character class , so that it would match an digit or a dot.

```
[\d.]
```

Comment: They are testing individual keystroke characters turned into a simple string.  No need for as much as you have in the regex.  Could just do `[\d.]`.

Comment: @AvinashRaj and how about allowing only single dot and no any other symbol in the text box with the same code -  `/^[.\d]+$/.test` 

I guess the following should work? 
`^\d+(?:\.\d+)?$`

Comment: just `/^\d+(?:\.\d+)?$/` use this regex and check against the whole string not char by char. This allows both integer and floating point numbers. To allow only floating point, you need to remove the last `?` symbol.

Comment: with `"return /^\d+(?:\.\d+)?$/.test(String.fromCharCode(((event||window.event).which||(event||window.event).which)));"` it does not accept dot or any other symbol.

Comment: test the regex against the whole string. This won't allow a single dot only.

Comment: i need to allow only a single dot. Example, "20.16" meters. Quotes value is in text box. 20 it allows but .16 its not.

Comment: problem is not with the regex but there is something in the code.

Comment: `<input onkeypress="return /^\d+(?:\.\d+)?$/.test(String.fromCharCode(((event||window.event).which||(event||window.event).which)));"
                            ondrop="return false" onpaste="return false" 
                            maxlength="8" type="text" />` 

Here's it which doesn't accept dot now.

Comment: Cannot accept right now. 
[link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25053605/regex-to-allow-only-a-single-dot-in-a-textbox) say similar answer of yours. Help me.